# Calculating the Overflow Flag in an ALU

Tags: logic, vhdl, cpu

First of all, forgive me if this isn't the right place to post this question, but I wasn't sure where it should go. I am currently working on simulating an ALU in Xilinx with VHDL. The ALU has the following inputs and outputs:

**Inputs**

- ***A*** and ***B***: two 8-bit operands
- ***Ci***: single-bit carry in
- ***Op***:  4-bit opcode for the multiplexers

**Outputs**

- ***Y***: 8-bit output operands
- ***Co***: single-bit carry out
- ***V***: overflow flag (1 if there is overflow, 0 otherwise)
- ***Z***: zero flag (1 if zero, 0 otherwise)
- ***S***: sign flag (1 if -ve, 0 if +ve)

The ALU performs the operations detailed in the table below:

[image: table here]

I have implemented it using multiplexers and an adder, as illustrated in the diagram below:

[image: here]

My question is:

> How do I calculate the value of the overflow flag, **V**?

I am aware that:

- If adding a positive to a negative, overflow will not occur
- If there is no carry/borrow, then the overflow can be calculated by evaluating the expression

```vhdl
(not A(7) and not B(7) and Y(7)) or (A(7) and B(7) and not Y(7))
```

where *A(7)*, *B(7)* and *Y(7)* are the 8th bit of ***A***, ***B*** and ***Y***     respectively.

- In the case of a carry/borrow, There is an overflow if and only if the carry-in and carry-out of the most significant bit are different.

I don't know how to implement this logically in VHDL code however - especially in the case of a carry.

Comment: [The CARRY flag and OVERFLOW flag in binary arithmetic](http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2343/10f/notes/040_overflow.txt), see the two methods of calculating the overflow flag. Your block diagram seems like it could be optimized there appears to be redundancy in the muxes. Consider asking design problems on [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vhdl).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution you have posted

```
v <= (not A(7) and not B(7) and Y(7)) or (A(7) and B(7) and not Y(7))
```

is correct for addition of signed operands and independent of the carry.

**EDIT** To use this also for your substraction, you have to use the actual adder inputs instead, i.e.:

```
v <= (not add_A(7) and not add_B(7) and Y(7)) or (add_A(7) and add_B(7) and not Y(7))
```

The above will work both for addition and substraction is independent of carry or borrow. (By the way, for the real implementation you should use `add_Y` instead of `Y` to shorten critical paths.)

If you want to implement it by XOR'ing the carry-in and carry-out of the most-signifcant sum bit, then you have to calculate a partial sum of the lowest 7 bit first. This gives you access to carry-out of bit 6 which is the carry-in of bit 7. Then just append a full-adder to get bit 7 and the carry-out. Here is the code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity adder_overflow is
  port (
    a  : in  unsigned(7 downto 0);
    b  : in  unsigned(7 downto 0);
    y  : out unsigned(7 downto 0);
    v  : out std_logic;
    co : out std_logic);
end;

architecture rtl of adder_overflow is
  signal psum   : unsigned(7 downto 0); -- partial sum
  signal c7_in  : std_logic;
  signal c7_out : std_logic;
begin

  -- add lowest 7 bits together
  psum <= ("0" & a(6 downto 0)) + b(6 downto 0);

  -- psum(7) is the carry-out of bit 6 and will be the carry-in of bit 7
  c7_in         <= psum(7);
  y(6 downto 0) <= psum(6 downto 0);

  -- add most-signifcant operand bits and carry-in from above together using a full-adder
  y(7)   <= a(7) xor b(7) xor c7_in;
  c7_out <= ((a(7) xor b(7)) and c7_in) or a(7);

  -- carry and overflow
  co <= c7_out;
  v  <= c7_in xor c7_out;
end rtl;
```

Comment: That looks great! My logic was - I'm not sure if it coincides with yours - I thought that V = 0 iff S = Co. Otherwise, V=1. Is that right? (S is the MSB of Y and Co is the carry-out).

Comment: @LukeCollins No. If you add "11111111" to "00000000", then S=1, V=0, Co = 0.

Comment: Ah... I see that. Thanks for the reply. I can't seem to get why you used XOR though - could you clarify?

Comment: @LukeCollins There are many XORs in my code. Which one do you mean?

Comment: The definition of V on the last line

Comment: @LukeCollins The overflow is 1 if carry-in and carry-out of bit 7 differ. And this is exactly what an XOR calculates.

Comment: @LukeCollins I updated my answer to also cover substraction.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution

`(not A(7) and not B(7) and Y(7)) or (A(7) and B(7) and not Y(7))`

and the text below it only apply to signed addition; it's not correct for subtraction. The two rules are:

1. Signed integer overflow of the expression *x*+*y*+*c* (where *c* is 0 or 1) occurs if and only if *x* and *y* have the same sign and the result has sign opposite to that of the operands (this is your equation), and
2. Signed integer overflow of the expression *x*-*y*-*c* (where *c* is again 0 or 1) occurs if and only if *x* and *y* have opposite signs, and the sign of the result is opposite to that of *x* (or, equivalently, the same as that of *y*).

Note that these are true whatever the value of the carry/borrow. You can see that the first rule doesn't apply for subtraction with a simple 4-bit example: 4 minus (-4), for example, must overflow because the answer should be +8, which isn't representable in 4 bits. In binary, this is `0100 - 1100 = 1000`. This is an overflow acording to (2), but not (1).

The good news is that xor-ing the carry into the sign bit and the carry out of the sign bit always works - it's correct for addition and subtraction, and whether or not there's a carry- or a borrow-in, so you can use Martin's code.

You should get a copy of Henry Warren's [Hacker's Delight](http://www.hackersdelight.org/) if you're going to do much arithmetic. He covers all this, and much more.

Comment: Hacker's delight. You must be referring to this book: https://books.google.ch/books/about/Hacker_s_Delight.html?id=XD9iAwAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y . However, the link you supplied does not appear to be directly relevant (or I have missed something).

Comment: @6v6gt: you're right, the website's down. He's getting on and may have died by now. Nice chap - he sent me a second copy of the book because there were a few pages missing in my one.

Comment: Interesting that you see the site at the link in your post as down. When I click on it, I get directed to a site called "Hacker's Delight" www.hackersdelight.org but it is the French language and deals with general advice on Health, Cars, Family, House, Fashion etc. There is a section of Informatics but not in any depth, stuff like how to clean a hard disk etc. The book sounds good though.

Answer (score 0):

Overflow occurs if the addition of two positive numbers gives a negative number and if the addition of two negative numbers gives a positive. That is, you need to compare the MSB of the operands and the answer. If the sign of the operands and the sign of the answer don't match, the overflow flag is turned on.

Edit: This only applies to situations where there is no carry. I need help too when it comes to additions with carry.

Comment: You'll see that I already included that point in my question.